# Function returning List(Of Structure)

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, revit-api

I have a function that is returning a `List(Of StructSection)`, with `StructSection` being defined like this:

```
Public Structure StructSection 'structure for Section information
    Public SectionName As String
    Public SectiontmpName As String
    Public SectionNewName As String
    Public Section As Autodesk.Revit.DB.View
End Structure
```

When I try to use that list in my `Sub Main`, I get this message:

> Type 'StructSection' is not defined. (BC30002)

Since I haven't defined it, that makes sense to me.  But, when I do define it by pasting the `StrucSection` definition above into my main code, I get this error:

> Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of FSE.frmRenameSections.StructSection)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of FSE.ThisDocument.StructSection)'.`

Even though the two structures were defined exactly in the same way.  Can anyone tell me how to use that `List(of StructSection)`?  What I'm really trying to do is make sure that for each result in the list, the `SectionName`, `SectiontmpName`, `SectionNewName` and `Section` stay associated with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.NET is a type-safe language.  That means, among other things, that if you declare the same type twice, they are considered to be two completely different and incompatible types, even if they contain the exact same members.

Try this:

```
Sub Main()
    ' ...
    Dim result As List(Of FSE.frmRenameSections.StructSection) = MyMethod()
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Where `MyMethod` is the name of the method that's returning the list.

Comment: It works when I build my solution, however when I try to run my macro, it gives me this error :`System.FormatException: input string was not in a correct format.`
When I comment out that `Dim Result` line, the error goes away, so I know it comes from that line. Any idea what it could be? I am not using `Result` yet, just defining it.

Comment: That's unrelated.  It must be a bug somewhere in the code.  It's impossible to say what the problem is, since you didn't post any of the code in the method.  The exception will give the full stack trace and, if in debug, it'll even give you the line number of the line that caused the exception.

Comment: Alright, I will do some more digging on my side and see if I can find out what causes that then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your first error message mentions two different classes: `FSE.frmRenameSections.StructSection` and `FSE.ThisDocument.StructSection`. To me, this looks as if you defined the same class twice in different scopes. Try splitting the `StructSection` into an own self-contained stand-alone class that is not embedded within any other class. Or, if it is embedded within some other class, name it explicitly with its full class name including the embedding hierarchy.